# Adding a dynamic link to an image in FPDF

Tags: php, fpdf

Hi I have an FPDF page I am working on and I want to connect a URL to a social media icon, now I know how to do this by adding a link like below.

```
$pdf->Image('images/facebook.png',10,47,8,0,'','http://www.facebook.com');
```

but i want to use a dynamic link, for example.

```
$facebook = $row['facebook'];
$pdf->Image('images/facebook.png',10,47,8,0,'','$facebook');
```

However it doesn't read the value of the facebook variable, I have tried reading up on various sites, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Maybe `"$facebook"`? (double quotes). Or without the single quotes?

Comment: I didnt even consider that, i just assumed it was the structure of my FPDF code, but you got it thank you., if you add it as an answer i will tick.  Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
$facebook = $row['facebook'];
$pdf->Image('images/facebook.png',10,47,8,0,'','$facebook');
```

The fix:

```
$pdf->Image('images/facebook.png',10,47,8,0,'',"{$facebook}");
```